# URP Spot Light braking Point Light

Tags: unity-game-engine, light, urp

Im using unity 2021.3.16f1 and I'm still having this issue with point lights and spot lights, my spot light that acts like a flashlight overrides all of the point lights in my scene, I already cleared the cache and I'm using additional Lights with Per Pixel, I also tried to change the per object limit to 8 and still it doesn't help.

[image]

this is my spot light config, and I have 10 point lights all over the scene with this config:
[image]

the point lights are really far from the spot light, and it seems like all of my point lights is acting like my spot light:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found that the solution is to set the "Universal Renderer Data" to use Rendering Path as Deferred